# how to get a device class specific descriptor with libusb

Tags: c, usb, libusb

I'm working with libusb and I need to get the device class specific descriptor for the hardware I'm working on.

I didn't find any function that could help me, does anyone have a clue about how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you refer the libusb documentation here -> http://www.libusb.org/?

Comment: There is a function `int libusb_get_device_descriptor (libusb_device *dev, struct libusb_device_descriptor *desc)` which could solve your purpose I think. What is the expected output?

Comment: I saw that function too, but it returns a structure representing the standard USB device descriptor, it doesn't have information related to the hardware I'm working on.

Comment: Read this -> http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__desc.html

Comment: could you be more specific? I have read that many times.

Comment: Could you be more specific what kind of information related to hardware you want? ProductId, VendorId?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same situation in checking the ways to get class specific descriptors and saw this question was unanswered.

libusb doesn't have any API or Data Structures to retrieve the class specific descriptors. This may be because libusb is designed only to address the basic USB specification. To get the class specific descriptor details using libusb, there are few extra fields added in each descriptor.

**Fields:** copied from libusb.h

```
/** Extra descriptors. If libusb encounters unknown endpoint descriptors,
 * it will store them here, should you wish to parse them. */
const unsigned char *extra;

/** Length of the extra descriptors, in bytes. */
int extra_length;
```

Both "extra" and "extra_length" is added in libusb_endpoint_descriptor, libusb_interface_descriptor, libusb_config_descriptor. You have to manually decode this content according to your class codes (either at configuration level or interface level descriptor).

You can refer [lsusb.c](https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/blob/master/lsusb.c#L488) in usbutils package for better understanding on decoding.

Answer (score 0):

If libusb does not have a specialized function for getting the data that you want, you should be able to use the `libusb_control_transfer` function (or the asynchronous version of that function) to fetch it.  The USB descriptors are all fetched via control transfers, so you can just do the appropriate control transfer using that function.